# Windows Phone 8 Geolocator can't set desiredAccuracy = High AND tie into PositionChanged event

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-8, geolocation, abort

background: I'm well versed in WPF/XAML, but new to Windows Phone 8.

Hopefully there is just something stupid that I'm missing...

I want DesiredAccuracy to be high, but I also want to hook into the PositionChanged event.

When the below code reaches _GeoLocator.DesiredAccuracy = PositionAccuracy.High; it throws an abort.  If it off, everything works but I really want high accuracy.

It seems the two are mutually exclusive of one another.

Error message is:  Operation aborted (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004004 (E_ABORT)).  I have Location capabilities enabled.

Example of offending code:

```
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _GeoLocator.MovementThreshold = 1;

        _GeoLocator.PositionChanged += (Geolocator sender, PositionChangedEventArgs args) =>
        {
            //UpdateLocation(args);
            Console.WriteLine("Position Changed");
        };

        //THIS WILL THROW...WHY??   IF I COMMENT OFF POSITIONCHANGED ABOVE, IT WORKS FINE.
        _GeoLocator.DesiredAccuracy = PositionAccuracy.High;
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to set "DesiredAccuracy" before "PositionChanged" event handler ([Similar question](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/wpapps/en-US/1c378213-68e6-4a54-a65c-c9ff21ad4414/update-geolocatormovementthreshold?forum=wpdevelop)).

```
_GeoLocator.MovementThreshold = 1;
_GeoLocator.DesiredAccuracy = PositionAccuracy.High;
_GeoLocator.PositionChanged += (Geolocator sender, PositionChangedEventArgs args) =>
    {
        //UpdateLocation(args);
        Console.WriteLine("Position Changed");
    };
```

Comment: Thanks...that's the winner.

From the (Similar question) link posted:

"You are not allowed to change any of the notification parameters (MovementThreshold, DesiredAccuracy, or ReportInterval) while you are getting location. This includes position changed (PositionChanged event) as well as getting position async (GetPositionAsync). If you want to change the notification parameters you must unsubscribe from all events and/or wait until GetPositionAsync has completed and then make the change."