# How to display signal of GPS weak or high in windows phone 8?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-8, gps

I am working on location tracking application. Everything is fine but the problem is when GPS is weak the application is running and showing wrong values. So what I need is, if the GPS signal strength is high or weak a text label should display high and weak. If and only if the text is high(GPS signal) the application should run. I have taken code from this link [nokia community](http://developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/A_Windows_Phone_8_Run_Tracking_App_in_100_Lines_of_Code!). Is it possible to trace GeoPositionAccuracy compared to any value or boolean?

Answer (score 1):

Try using the HorizontalAccuracy and VerticalAccuracy properties of a GeoCoordinate.

```
private void Watcher_PositionChanged(object sender, GeoPositionChangedEventArgs<GeoCoordinate> e){
    if(Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(e.Position.Location.HorizontalAccuracy,2) + Math.Pow(e.Position.Location.VerticalAccuracy,2)) < Tolerance_In_Meters)
        //accurate enough
    else
        //not accurate enough
}
```

[GeoCoordinate Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.device.location.geocoordinate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Full disclosure: I've never used this.

Comment: can u pls explain what is Tolerance_In_Meters and why it is < accuracy? If GPS signal is high, wihtout using Math functions I was getting correct values . Is it necessary to take Math functions in this line?

Comment: @madhu Tolerance_In_Meters is the margin of error that your code can live with. So if you can't have the GPS be more than 10 meters off of where the phone actually is, than set it to 10. The math functions are just to calculate the Euclidean or "ordinary" distance of the error as opposed to the [Manhatten Distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manhattan_distance)

Answer (score 1):

You can use Horizontal and Vertical accuracy.

```
Geolocator geolocator = new Geolocator();
geolocator.DesiredAccuracy = PositionAccuracy.High;
```

[Attention - DesiredAccuracy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19172451/windows-phone-8-geolocator-cant-set-desiredaccuracy-high-and-tie-into-positio/19176485#19176485)

```
geolocator.ReportInterval = ....; // or MovementThreshold
geolocator.PositionChanged += GeolocatorPositionChanged;

double YOUR_HORIZONTAL_ACCURACY = 20; // accuracy in metres
double YOUR_VERTICAL_ACCURACY = 20;   // accuracy in metres

private void GeolocatorPositionChanged(Geolocator sender, PositionChangedEventArgs args)
{
    GeoCoordinate coordinate = args.Position.Coordinate.ToGeoCoordinate(); // ToGeoCoordinate method is extension from the Windows Phone Toolkit

    if ((Double.IsNaN(coordinate.HorizontalAccuracy) || coordinate.HorizontalAccuracy > YOUR_HORIZONTAL_ACCURACY) && (Double.IsNaN(coordinate.VerticalAccuracy) || coordinate.VerticalAccuracy > YOUR_VERTICAL_ACCURACY))
    {
        // weak
    }

    else
    {
        // high
    }
```